# Devise login through JSON Rails 4 API

Tags: json, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

How exactly can I allow a user to login remotely by sending an encrypted password/email to the devise controllers so I can issue them an API key that I already have setup? Sorry, this whole realm of technology is very new too me, so apologies for the n00b question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to go through the Devise controllers. Assuming you are `post`ing to a `sign_in` action:

```
def sign_in
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

  if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    sign_in user
    #now current_user == user
    #you logic to return the api key
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now but I'll see how this technique goes. My one question is, how exactly do I encrypt the password with same method as devise so that it can compare them, I don't exactly want to send unencrypted passwords over the web.

Comment: This is obviously a step in the direction though.

Comment: You should you `ssl` and `https` when sending sensitive material. I do not think pre-encrypting the password on the client side is a viable option

Comment: I was thinking https/ssl was the way to go, that seems like the best option. I'll mark this answer as correct once I get the chance to implement it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You will have to be more specific. Will you be passing the user's API key for authentication in the headers? If so, you can have a before_filter for every action that requires authentication to check the validity of the API key. If the API key is not valid, you can `sign_out current_user if current_user`

Comment: Your solution worked liked a charm! I guess the next step is determining when to invalidate the keys.

Comment: So being incredibly naive, I didn't realize that you could just send JSON objects to the devise controllers and they work as expected. Also since I didn't remove the session part of the Rails stack, the API key only works when the user is considered logged in.